# error: narrowing conversion of ‘194’ from ‘int’ to ‘char’ inside { }

Tags: c++, espeak

I am trying to compile [eSpeak](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/) for a related project but getting this error after running the make command.

```
tr_languages.cpp:201:43: error: narrowing conversion of ‘194’ from 
‘int’ to ‘char’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
const char string_ordinal[] = {0xc2,0xba,0};  // masculine ordinal 
character, UTF-8
                                       ^
tr_languages.cpp:201:43: error: narrowing conversion of ‘186’ from     
‘int’ to ‘char’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
Makefile:102: recipe for target 'tr_languages.o' failed
make: *** [tr_languages.o] Error 1
```

I searched about it and it appears that here the declaration of

```
const char string_ordinal[] = {0xc2,0xba,0};
```

should have been

```
const signed char string_ordinal[] = {0xc2,0xba,0};
```

Since the source code is large to change, is there any other way to compile it successfully?

I am using gcc version 6.2.0 20161005 (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12)

Comment: you mean unsigned char right? anyway, compiler tells you how to turn off the warning: `-Wno-narrowing`

Comment: Or use `-funsigned-char` to make chars unsigned

Comment: Is it fixed? I am facing the same problem

Comment: After digging around, I fixed it by changing that line to `const char string_ordinal[] = {(char)0xc2,(char)0xba,0};  // masculine ordinal character, UTF-8`