# NS 2 Installation error : narrowing conversion of 252 from int to char

Tags: security, networking, ns2

I am working on VANET. for that, i need to install NS2 on my fedora 24 system. NS 2 version - ns 2.34 . During the installation process, i followed all the steps of ns 2.34 and made changes in the respective files. But at last, i found an error like the one attached in the screenshot. 
Error:  narrowing conversion of 252 from 'int' to 'char' inside play.xbm

I am unable to solve this error. Please guide me for this. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C29ch.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) ! Please read  [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) !

Comment: @jenis shah : Images with text are not appreciated. Don't do, please. → Unreadable text, cannot be copied . ... I guess you know how to copy / paste a text to an empty file.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem.

Refer to:[error: narrowing conversion of ‘194’ from ‘int’ to ‘char’ inside { }](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40194752/error-narrowing-conversion-of-194-from-int-to-char-inside)

Add`-funsigned-char` to the L48 of the `Makefile` in the `/ns-allinone-2.34/nam-1.15` directory

image:
[the code was added like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBG1f.png)

Answer (score 0):

> i followed all the steps of ns 2.34

Some old "ns2 tutorials" were valid only for a very short time.

Fedora 24 :

Your compiling errors : g++ version 6.3 is OK with ns-2.34, but **patching is required**. I.e. ns-2.34 was built for g++ version 4.1.2.

ns234_gcc49.patch https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNZDNyV1BPZHhEY0U/view?usp=sharing

```
cd ns-allinone-2.34/
patch -p0 < ns234_gcc49.patch
./install
```

---

---

P.S. : `ns-allinone-2.34 + ns234_gcc49.patch` was tested OK with two different Fedora 24 : The 64bits version and the 32bits version. `ns-allinone-2.34` can of course also be compiled as is / no changes : `export CC=gcc34 CXX=g++34 && ./install`

Requires : # `dnf install compat-gcc-34-c++`